# Postgresql sequence always 1

Tags: postgresql, sequence, postgresql-9.5

I have an application that often does insertion into PostgreSQL database, for some tables I have `id` column with `serial` type with auto-generated sequences. Running

```
SELECT nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('client', 'id'));
```

on each new session gives 1. What should I do to correct this, or I need to this manually in my app?

For last case, I think get total records and alter sequence, but this is 2 more queries to do, which I better skip.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is how sequences in PostgreSQL generally behave.

You must have some rogue process which is issuing a command such as:

```
alter sequence client_id_seq restart;
```

Or something equivalent to that.  Figure out what is issuing that command, and make it stop.

If you can't figure out who is sabotaging your sequence, there are a variety of ways to figure it out.  One is to crank up your log level by setting `log_statement` to 'ddl' or 'all', and look in the logs.  Another is to make your table and sequence owned by a role which does not normally log into the database, and grant rights to the table and sequence to the normal log-in users.  They will then get errors when they try to reset the sequence, because only the owner can do that.  (This is a good practice anyway, to have objects owned by special roles which do not log in except when it is necessary to change the schema.)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful, I'll test my db with your suggestions

Comment: `because only the owner can do that`. And superusers, of course. And `SECURITY DEFINER` functions owned by either.